# How to assign a gradient of color to plotted points based on values of numeric column in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have a large data frame with a ton of observations. The data frame is called `totdets_per_month`and the first lines of data looks like this:

```
  month yearcollected deploy_long deploy_lat total
  <ord>         <int>       <dbl>      <dbl> <int>
1 Jan            2016       -54.6       39.9     1
2 Jan            2016       -54.6       39.9     2
3 Jan            2016       -54.6       39.9     9
4 Jan            2016       -54.4       39.9     9
5 Jan            2016       -54.4       39.9     2
6 Jan            2016       -54.4       39.9     2
```

I have data for all months at a range of coordinates,

I'm trying to map these coordinates as points, but have the points assigned to a gradient of color based on my numeric column `total`.

This is my code to plot the dataframe

```
#Importing a map
world = ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")


#map of total detections in each zone per month
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill = "lightgrey") +
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_rect(data = rect1, aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = y1, ymax = y2), fill = NA, color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = totdets_per_month ,
             mapping = aes(x = deploy_long, 
                           y = deploy_lat,
                           fill = total),
             pch = 21) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="black", high="green") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#add8e6"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(vars(month))
```

This is the image the code outputs 
[image]

as you can see the points are all one color. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: From the sample data you posted the typical values appear to be less than 10, but the max on color scale is >2000. Are you sure you don't have one or two extreme values and the remaining values are close to 1? The other option to try is to add `color=total` to your aes definition.

Comment: yes you are totally right. There are a few extreme values, but why aren't those even showing on the map. Also, if that is the reason, is there a better way to map this to show all the values? Also when I try `color = total` in the aes definition along with fill I get the same issue

Comment: Notice the color scale is going from black to blue and not to green.  You have a problem with your aes definition.  In your aes, you are specifying fill=total, but you are only defining `scale_colour_gradient`, first change `scale_colour_gradient` to `scale_fill_gradient`, then plot.

Comment: yes, that was the problem. Guess I'll have to try and average my data to try and get smaller values

Answer (score 1):

This is a consolidated answer based on my comments above:

Notice the color scale is going from black to blue and not to green. You have a problem with your aes definition. In your aes, you are specifying "fill=total", but you are only defining `scale_colour_gradient`, first change `scale_colour_gradient` to `scale_fill_gradient`.

```
#create sample data
x<- runif(20, 1, 20)
y<-x^4
df<-data.frame(x, y)

library(ggplot2)
#this is a linear scale for the colors
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=y), pch=21, size=4) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="black", high="green")
```

[image]

In the plot above the few extremely large values of y is causing most of the remaining points to plot black.  In order to adjust for this skewing the color scale, then you will need to manually specify the color breaks. 
In the example below, I used the `cut` function to divide my range by the power of 10 and assign break to a different color value.

```
#create color ramp
colfunc <-colorRampPalette(c("black", "green"))

#adjust scaling of the colors and 
#  add custom color color to dataframe
df$color<-cut(y, breaks=c(0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, Inf))
df$color<-factor(df$color, labels=colfunc(5))

ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=color), pch=21, size=4) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide="legend", labels=c(10^(1:5)))
```

[image]

Now the plot does a better job of showing the distribution.